# android set listener on canvas

Tags: android, listener, android-canvas

is it possible to set a listener in a canvas so that it will react when it's clicked??

I'm confused because I want to draw an image with x y coordinates as well as setting the clickListener to the image...

if so then, please show the codes....

THX , I appreciate your help....

Answer (score 4):

A Canvas is not a View in Android. You can add a onClickListener to a View. You may want to look into SurfaceView, which is a View, if you want to do drawing.

Some links

- [Graphics](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html)
- [Surface View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html)
- [Example](http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-ii,160.html)